# Reorder array in pascal, descending

Tags: arrays, sql-order-by, pascal

couldn't find similar posts, so posting my own question.
I got variable array of real:

```
price = array([58.9],[38.7],[8.95],[28.3])
```

I need to order it descending, with my code everything works well until last value of the array, I know even why, but can't find solution on my own. Anyway here's the code:

```
    Procedure orderarray;
Var i,dz, j: Integer;
  c  :real;
  v  :string[25];

Begin
dz := 1;
 For i := 1 to 3 do
  Begin
   For j:=i+1 to 4 do
    if price[j]>price[dz] //searches for highest value in the array
       then dz:=j;
   c:=price[i]; price[i] := price[dz]; price[dz] := c; //switches current value with highest
  End;
```

Comment: you should turn that into the answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution to my own problem. Posting it just in case anyone will need it. I needed to reset dz to i, not j

```
    Procedure orderarray;
Var i,dz, j: Integer;
  c  :real;
  v  :string[25];

Begin
 For i := 1 to 3 do
  Begin
dz:=i;
   For j:=i+1 to 4 do
    if price[j]>price[dz] //searches for highest value in the array
       then dz:=j;
   c:=price[i]; price[i] := price[dz]; price[dz] := c; //switches current value with highest
  End;
```

Thank you everybody for your help, wouldn't get to the solution without you, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset dz to j everytime

```
for j:=i+1 to 4 do
begin
   dz := j;
   if price[j]>price[dz]
      ...;
   c:=price[i]; ...;
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you set dz to j?

Answer (score 0):

In your sample dz will remain always 1, last element will never be moved since it is less then the first.

Comment: I understand that myself, but how to arrange my procedure so that it would work I have no idea.